# Find file location in CMD and use it

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to find `php.exe` file on any given machine (windows). The problem is that I don't know where to find the `php.exe` file because the path may change a bit. I'm trying to find the `php.exe` file that comes with wamp.

The problem is that wamp changes the file path based on the php version. For example, on one version the path will be: `c:/wamp/bin/php5.5.2/php/php.exe` and on another it will be `c:/wamp/bin/php5.4.1/php/php.exe`

I need a way to find the path to that `php.exe` file so I can use it and run php files:
`c:/wamp/bin/php5.5.2/php/php.exe -f "path/to/my/php/file.php"`

I tried doing someting like:

```
cd c:/wamp
dir /S /P php.exe
```

and I get as a result the folder of the file along with more details such as the file size and more. However, I have no clue how I can take only the desired information, the location, and use it in another batch command that will do what I want with it.

example of output (searching within **c:/xampp** [don't have wamp on this machine yet.]):

> Volume in drive C has no label.  Volume Serial Number is 1SD-23F
>
> Directory of c:\xampp\php
>
> 07/24/2014  12:24 AM            65,536 php.exe
>                  1 File(s)         65,536 bytes
>
> ```
>  Total Files Listed:
>            1 File(s)         65,536 bytes
>            0 Dir(s)  354,231,255,040 bytes free
> ```

As you can see it tells me that th path is `c:\xampp\php` now all I have to do is to somehow take it, append `\php.exe -f "path/to/my/file.php"` and done.

Comment: Maybe use /b and a for loop

Comment: @MisterHenson Can you be a little bit more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is only one instance/version of the file

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "c:\wamp\php.exe" /a-d /b /s') do set "php=%%a"
    echo %php%

    "%php%" -f "c:\somewhere\your\file.php"
```

The `dir` command will search all instances of the php executable. `dir` is executed by the `for` command that iterates over the `dir` output. For each line, the code in the `do` clause is executed.

Comment: Aren't you assuming the php file location `c:/wamp/php.exe`? Or you  actually saying to look within `c:/wamp`for any `php.exe` file?

Comment: @kfirba, `dir /a-d /s /b "c:\wamp\php.exe"` = retrieve not folders, search into subdirectories, list in bare format, a `php.exe` file under `c:\wamp` (and below, as we are looking into subdirectories). Try to run the `dir` from command line to see its output (that will be processed by the `for` command)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot. Exactly what I needed, does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Use `where`. To search from the current directory and `PATH` environment variable:

```
where php.exe
```

To search a specific directory structure:

```
where /R c:\wamp php.exe
```

Comment: that does the job. But how do I use the output?

Answer (score 0):

I came later, but with purely PHP solution

```
function getPhpPath() {
    $pattern = '/php[0-9\.]*/i';
    $mainPath = "C:/wamp/bin";
    foreach(scandir("C:/wamp/bin") as $dir) {
        if(preg_match($pattern, $dir)) {
            return $mainPath . '/' . $dir;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Or just `glob("C:/wamp/bin/php*");`

Comment: but the real answer is to always add the php.exe to your environment variable PATH. and after that a simple call for php.exe will be done perfectly without any problem

Comment: Thanks for answer but it is a little bit irrelevant since it has to be done through CMD and I need the php path so I can run php script  :/